# Default title doesn't show , instead shows homepage title

Tags: magento-1.9

I am unable to figure out why the default title doesn't show on my page title. The page title is instead displaying the name of the cms home page. How do I stop displaying the page name? 
Here's the screenshot & [link](http://www.singhcycle.com) to the site.

[image: Default Title]

Comment: The default title will show if the CMS page title is blank ( it will never happen) you need to change the title in each CMS page

Comment: I understand, the page title of homepage cannot be left blank and I need to  change the title of each CMS page. If I have to do so, then what's the benefit HTML Head>Default Title?

Comment: it will show on your category and product pages

Comment: your CMS Page title is blank???

Comment: No! CMS page title is a required field.

Comment: Pls add in field : Title Prefix =>Singhcycle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default title 
in head.phtml replace :

```
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
```

with :

```
<title><?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_title'); ?></title>
```

You can add condition to use the default title if CMS Page

```
if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName() === 'cms) : 
<title><?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_title'); ?></title>
else:
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

***This is what I learnt.***

CMS page title doesn't override default title. It's not possible to suppress the CMS page title, unless you fiddle with core files, which isn't really advisable. Simply, updating the CMS page titles would do the trick. Default Title is for mainly products & categories pages. I have decided to keep my Default Title & Home Page CMS page title the same. This works for me.